# Shorten MATLAB equation with huge fractions

Tags: matlab, simulink, equation

I have an equation with big fractions:

```
charEquation = (1226445470683446638330217*k1)/4503599627370496000000000 - (41600478995284454232578811*k2)/28823037615171174400000000 - ...
```

How can I shorten the equation so there are smaller factors?
Ex:

```
0.2723*k1 - (1.4433*k2 - .....
```

Thank you for your answers

To reproduce a small version of the problem use the following MATLAB code

```
syms k1 k2 k3 s; 
sMatrix = [s 0 0 ; 0 s 00; 0 0 s ]; 
kMatrix = [k1; k2; k3]; 
aMatrix = [1.234 23.2 2.43; 1.24 3.2 1.43; 1.4 2.2 2.3]; 
charEquation = sMatrix-(aMatrix*kMatrix)
```

Comment: Thanks! my question to you is now: why do you want to do it? if you evaluate `1226445470683446638330217/4503599627370496000000000` you may lose precission due to numerical issues, and the entire point of using symbolic math is to not lose precision. `0.2723` is not equal to that fraction, just approximately equal. The real number is `0.27232559999999997620406078091548`, which is not much shorter

Comment: I do not need high precision. I just need it it decimal places precise.

Comment: Then don't use `syms` I guess.